# Trouble with nested loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

With the definition of Big-Oh, I'm required to prove $\log_b(g(n))$ is big-oh of $\log_b(f(n))$. I may assume $g(n)$ is big-oh of $f(n)$, $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are eventually $\geq b$ and $b > 1$.

However, I'm stuck and I don't know where to being or what to do even. Any hints towards proving $\log_b(g(n))$ is big-oh of $\log_b(f(n))$?

BTW, $\log_b$ means $\log$ base $b$. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

def nested(n):

```
"""Assume n is an integer and n > 1."""

b = 1

while b <= n:

    i = 1

    while i < b:
        print(i)
        i = i*3
    b = b + 1
```

Comment: The assumptions you are supposed to make allow you to conclude that there exists $c >0$ such that for large enough $n$ , $1 < b \leq g(n) \leq cf(n)$.  Specifically, for $b > 1$, $\log_b x$ is monotonically increasing for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since b>1 you can pull out the base b with log properties.
logb(a) = log(a) / log(b)
and then you end up trying to show that log(g(n)) is O(log(f(n)))
You can do this since b>1 and so log(b) > 0.

Not sure if that helps  :P
(I don't know how to make b a subscript, so by logb I meant log with base b.)

Comment: Thanks to [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you know now how to format maths in your posts!

Comment: @Harry 49  Thanks!  :P

Comment: @AsheKetchum That actually helps a lot! So, then what I need to prove comes down to this:

\exists c, n$_0$ \in R$^+$, \forall n \in N, n>= n$_0$ --> log(g(n)) <= c(log(f(n)). 

So, now I can just pick a c and n_0 to prove this using the definition right? I can't use any external properties of big-oh, just the definition of it. :/

Comment: @suugarpie I can't say I'm too familiar with big-oh, was looking at the question with my very limited knowledge :P I feel like what you are saying is right, and it reminds me of the 'Archimedean property', which will guarantee such a c exists when log(g(n)) and log(f(n)) are proportional. If I remember correctly that is :) I think your assumption might play a role here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Archimedean property (in fact its the first time i'm hearing it). I'm a noob at these things for forgive me. I was also thinking, since I know g(n) \in O(f(n)), then I know g(n) <= c(f(n)). I could take the log of both sides and use log property to show the assumption is the same as what i'm trying to prove, ya? 

Like g(n) <= c(f(n)) --> log(g(n)) <= log(c(f(n))) --> log(g(n)) <= c(log(f(n)) = log_b(g(n)) \in O(log_b(f(n)). Right?

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, however I am not sure if  O() allows that. If it does then you are done :)